# WebGl solar system

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, 3d, webgl

```
<input type="button" value="Mercury" class="btn" onClick = "showInfo(1)"/>
<div id="1" style="left:70%;top:300px;width:300px;position:absolute;z-index:100;display:none;">
    Mercury - my favorite planet
</div>
```

Venus - my favorite planet

```
<input type="button" value="Earth" class="btn3" onClick = "showInfo(3)"/>
<div id="3" style="left:70%;top:300px;width:300px;position:absolute;z-index:100;display:none;">
    earth - my favorite planet
</div>`
```

This is the button function for solar system navigation.

```
var infoMercury = false;    
var infoVenus = false;
var infoEarth = false;
```

Those are the variables.

```
if(!info){

    earth.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.2)*3000;
    earth.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.2)*3000;

    clouds.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.2)*3000;
    clouds.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.2)*3000;

    mercury.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.6)*800;
    mercury.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.6)*800;

    venus.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.4)*1700;
    venus.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.4)*1700;

    mars.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.16)*5000;
    mars.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.16)*5000;

    jupiter.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.12)*(-7400);
    jupiter.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.12)*(-7400);

    saturn.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.08)*9800;
    saturn.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.08)*9800;

    ring.position.x = saturn.position.x;
    ring.position.z = saturn.position.z;

    uranus.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.04)*12000;
    uranus.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.04)*12000;

    neptune.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.02)*18000;
    neptune.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.02)*18000;

    mercury.rotation.y+=0.01;
    venus.rotation.y+=0.01;
    earth.rotation.y+=0.005;
    clouds.rotation.y-=0.001;
    mars.rotation.y+=0.01;
    jupiter.rotation.y+=0.01;
    saturn.rotation.y+=0.01;
    ring.rotation.y-=0.002; //saturn ring
    uranus.rotation.y+=0.01;
    neptune.rotation.y+=0.01;
}

 else 

  {
      if(infoMercury){
        if(camera.position.z>mercury.position.z-100){
          camera.position.z-=80;
          camera.lookAt(mercury.position);
         }
         else
         {
             document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";

         }
          if(camera.position.x<mercury.position.x-100){
          camera.position.x+=80;
         }

    }

   if(infoVenus){
       if(camera.position.z>venus.position.z-100){
       camera.position.z-=80;
       camera.lookAt(venus.position);
       }
       else
         {
             document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";

         }
          if(camera.position.x<mercury.position.x-100){
          camera.position.x+=80;
         }

   }

   if(infoEarth){
        if(camera.position.z>earth.position.z-300){
          camera.position.z-=80;
          camera.lookAt(earth.position);
          }
         else
         {
             document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";

         }
          if(camera.position.x<earth.position.x-80){
          camera.position.x+=180;
         }
   }
```

The above code is the position and rotation of planets, and when pressing the button ,the camera directs to the specific planet and show the info.

```
function showInfo(num){
    switch(num){
        case 1:
            infoMercury = true;
            info = true;
        break;
        case 2:
            infoVenus = true;
            info = true;
        break
        case 3:
            infoEarth = true;
            info = true;
        break;
        case 4:
            info = true;
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
```

When pressing one of the buttons ,it directs the camera to the location of the planet.
I have been having difficulties creating buttons for each planet location, thus when click on the navigation it only performs the tasks once.
For example if i click on the button "mercury" it finds the planet,showing the info ,but then when selecting another button ,the navigation falls in find the planet. Thus the information of the previous planet remains on the screen.

Any ideas how we can arrange the script for the navigation?

Comment: Your logic looks a little cumbersome, but it would work if you reset all other infoPlanet variables to false before the `switch` statement.

Comment: `function setVars(value) { 
info = false 
infoMercury = false 
infoVenus = false 
infoEarth = false 
value; } `.
Hello bfavaretto thanks for reply! I used this function before switch statement but there is no result. Maybe there is something wrong with the function that i used to set the variables to false? Or you can suggest me a different way to reset the variables?